# "Resolve to the same URL" and .htaccess file for HTML built website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A while ago I made my first website using only HTMl code and some basic inline CSS.
I don't have the experience and the intuitive knowledge of how things work in this world that is why even the most basic errors I have to solve or tweaks I have to make gives me headache.

My website looks like it's duplicated because when you enter the www or the non www version, then both work and for the search engines it looks like there are two identical websites, which is not good for me.
One tool showed me an error saying: "https://domain.lv and https://www.domain.lv should resolve to the same URL, but currently do not."
I've tried different methods to solve this by editing my .htaccess file, but nothing works. I'm sure there is some dumb mistake I am making because I don't know how should even basic things look like when they are right.

This here is my .htaccess file now (for this I used the word domain as a placeholder for my real domain name):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.lv [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.lv/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Do you see what is wrong here and how I get it right?
And maybe someone could give me a sample file of how .htaccess file should look like for websites built from scratch?

I will appreciate any help.
Cheers!

Comment: The www to non-www redirect you have looks OK. If it doesn't appear to do anything (if that's what you mean by "nothing works") then it's possible that `.htaccess` _overrides_ are not enabled on your server (ie. `.htaccess` files are not enabled)? Are you using extensionless URLs successfully?

Comment: Yes, by "nothing works" I meant that none of the htaccess file variations I tried worked. 
I'm not sure if I understand what extensionless URLs are. My URLs all have .html at the end. Another issue I haven't solved yet.
Just to add.. I am using DigitalOcean as my hist and I also use CloudFlare to handle my SSLs

Comment: "My URLs all have .html at the end" - so, you are not using "extensionless URLs" then. The 2nd rule allows you to use extensionless URLs, ie. your URLs should not have `.html` at the end. As it stands, this is potentially causing more "duplicate content". However, there is nothing to suggest that your `.htaccess` file is actually doing anything? Which is why I'm wondering whether this is enabled on your server? You may also have an issue with CloudFlare caching the old response? Try entering any _nonsense_ at the top of the `.htaccess` file - this should produce a 500 error.

Comment: I have LEMP server on Digital Ocean. As I understand Nginx does not use .htaccess files. What would be the alternative solution to this?

Comment: In that case you need to update your question.